# Starting an animation from the ViewModel in WPF/MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm writing a MVVM app and have started putting in a few animations. I want to call something on the ViewModel which starts the a storyboard. [This blog had a promising approach to it](http://chris.59north.com/post/mvvm-and-animations.aspx), but it doesn't actually work. The IDChanged handler never fires for some reason.

I also found that you could start animations on EventTriggers, but I don't know how to raise one on the ViewModel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up adding an AnimationStarted event to my ViewModel with a key string for what animation it is. Then on the view I create the animation programmatically, subscribe to the AnimationStarted event, and kick the appropriate animation off when it fires.

Answer (score 15):

I did this by a using DataTrigger and binding it to a property in my ViewModel.  When the "FlashingBackGround" property gets set to "ON" the Storyboard animation starts.

Also make sure to include in your project a reference to "Microsoft.Expression.Interactions"

XAML: (this goes directly in the root node)

```
<Window
   xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
   xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions" 
   x:Name="window" >

    ...

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <ei:DataTrigger Binding="{Binding FlashingBackground, Mode=OneWay}" Value="ON">
        <ei:ControlStoryboardAction Storyboard="{StaticResource MyAnimation}"     
                                                ControlStoryboardOption="Play"/>
      </ei:DataTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    ...
</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```
 private void TurnOnFlashingBackround()
    {
        FlashingBackground = "ON";
    }

    private string _FlashingBackround = "OFF";

    public string FlashingBackground
    {
        get { return _FlashingBackround; }

        private set
        {
            if (FlashingBackground == value)
            {
                return;
            }

            _FlashingBackround = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("FlashingBackground");
        }
    }

    public new event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Finally, the Viewmodel must inherit from "INotifyPropertyChanged"

Comment: Interesting approach. But why not just use a `boolean` instead of a "ON"/"OFF" string?

Comment: Make sure  to add the "System.Windows.Interactivity.dll" too.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem, and none of these posts really helped because the animations are in code, and some of them were large and complicated and required fluctuating variables so they had to stay in code. I resolved it by adding dependency properties in the user control (view) that trigger the animations, and binding them to properties in the view-model. Don't know (/care) if this violates something or other, because it works very well! cheers, stepp

excerpt:

(view) Usercontrol code behind:

```
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        SetAnimationBindings();
    }

    private void SetAnimationBindings()
    {
        _dialogStartPosition = mbFolderBrowse.Margin;

        var propName = "StartDialogAnimation";
        var binding = new Binding(propName) { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };
        this.SetBinding(DialogAnimationProperty, binding);

        propName = "StartProgressAnimation";
        binding = new Binding(propName) { Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay };
        this.SetBinding(ProgressAnimationProperty, binding);
    }

    #region Animation Properties
    #region DialogAnimation
    public static readonly DependencyProperty DialogAnimationProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("DialogAnimation", typeof(bool),
            typeof(Manage), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, OnDialogAnimationChanged));
    public bool DialogAnimation
    {

        get { return (bool)this.GetValue(DialogAnimationProperty); }
        set
        {
            var oldValue = (bool)this.GetValue(DialogAnimationProperty);
            if (oldValue != value) this.SetValue(DialogAnimationProperty, value);
        }
    }

    private static void OnDialogAnimationChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Manage m = o as Manage;

        if ((bool)e.NewValue == true)
            m.SlideInDialogPanel(); // animations
        else
            m.SlideOutDialogPanel();
    }
    #endregion
```

View-Model:

```
public bool StartDialogAnimation
{
    get { return _startDialogAnimation; }
    set
    {
        if (_startDialogAnimation != value)
        {
            _startDialogAnimation = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("StartDialogAnimation");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a property in my VM that reflects the state of the application. The elements in the view that are animated have a data trigger that starts a storyboard when the VM property has a certain value.

Comment: I know how to do that. You set up a trigger to start the storyboard when you enter a condition. But I just need to do a one-off animation: I want to do a quick, temporary flash on a UI element to bring attention to it.

Comment: I haven't considered generalizing this, so I don't know if this helps you. I once had a similar need. I had to 'flash' a button if there was no activity for a minute. I did this by having a storyboard attached to the button, the storyboard would do nothing for a minute then do the flash. In my case, the button went away when clicked so it made the scenario simpler. A flash on a UI element to grab attention sounds like view related only. Is there a way the view can determine when to to the flash by itself? Why would the VM care about flashing a UI element? Sorry, this may not be much help.

Comment: Well, several commands that fire on one window would trigger this flash in another window. My windowing model is set up such that the VM knows about the relationships between the windows, but the views do not.

Comment: Do you have some sample code on this DataTrigger? I tried that and it didn't really work out with my DataBindings

Comment: @Tigraine - I have a sample that uses the text value of a model item.