# Animating Image in MVVM on launch

Tags: wpf, animation, mvvm

I have a ImageViewModel , the view consist of an icon.
When I create the instance of ViewModel and when the view loads I want to animate the image to move it downwards.
How  to do that?

```
    <Image x:Name="TestImage" Width="75" Height="75"  Source="pack://application:,,,/TestProject.View;Component/Resources/TestImage.png">      
    </Image>
```

Comment: Maybe this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5971753/4377809) can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how i fixed it.I placed my image in a canvas. On userControl Loaded event im trigger an UserControl.Loaded event which will start my storyboard.

```
   <Canvas  DataContext="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Canvas.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger  RoutedEvent="UserControl.Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard >
                <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetName="Image1" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Canvas.Top)">                        
                    <DoubleAnimation From="0"  To="50" Duration="0:0:2" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Canvas.Triggers>
    <Image x:Name="Image1"  Grid.Row="1" Width="170" Height="192"  Source="{Binding ImageSource}">             
    </Image>
</Canvas >
```

Comment: You don't need to use a canvas, you can just use the image and change the margin instead for a similar result.